# DJANGO - multiple models in ListView

Tags: django, listview, django-models, detailsview

I want pass much models in ListView.

In fact, I want pass User model and Food model...

**my LIST VIEW**

```
class home(ListView):
    model=User 
    template_name="site/home.html"
    context_object_name="myusers"                               
    paginate_by = 5
```

**my DETAIL VIEW**

```
class boardUser(DetailView):
    model = User
    context_object_name = "user"
    template_name = "site/boarduser.html"
```

**my URL**

```
url(r'^home$', home.as_view(), name="home"),    
url(r'^boarduser/(?P<pk>\d+)',boardUser.as_view(), name="board-user"),
```

**my TEMPLATE**

```
{% for user in les_utilisateurs %}    
    <a href="{% url 'board-user' user.id %}"> {{ user.username }} </a>    
{% endfor %}
```

But I just pass User model, I don't pass Food model...

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: overwrite get_context_data in your view, see 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/
You can use mixin, like in sample or change the view

Comment: I want pass 2 models in ListView

Comment: Maybe look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812505/can-i-have-multiple-lists-in-a-django-generic-listview